# How to add UserControl.cs to Wpf Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I wanted to know is it possible to add UserControl.cs to Wpf Window
I tried my best finding way and I searched for any solution I didn't find
So I had this idea to ask anyone who can help me

Thank You

Comment: Hi, adding a `.cs` file to something is a bit odd. Can you explain what you're trying to do? Creating a user control perhaps?

Comment: yes that's what i mean

Comment: that what I meant to say

Comment: * .cs is a **File**.  
**Window** is a **class**.  
When the application starts, an instance of the Window class is created.  
Add **FILE** to **class** ...  
It is not at all clear what you need.  
  
Maybe you need to display an instance of the class declared in UserControl.cs in the Window class?  
  
Or add the UserControl.cs file to the drop-down Windows file group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following example:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="RPM.Client.WPF.Windows.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:Client.WPF.UserControls"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Client.WPF.ViewModels"
        Width="800"
        Height="600"
        WindowState="Maximized">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TConsole}">
            <uc:MainView_UC />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <dx:BackgroundPanel>
        <ContentControl x:Name="MainControl">
            <ContentControl.Content>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Text="Please wait. Loading data ..." />
                </StackPanel>

            </ContentControl.Content>
        </ContentControl>
    </dx:BackgroundPanel>

</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    public void SetContent(object content)
    {
        MainControl.Content = content;
    }
}
```

TConsole.cs:

```
public class TConsole : TViewModelBase
{
    #region Constructors

    static TConsole()
    {
        Instance = new TConsole();
        MainThread = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    }

    private TConsole()
    {
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
    }


    #endregion

    #region Fields
    private static TaskScheduler MainThread;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public static TConsole Instance { get; private set; }
    public MainWindow MainWindow { get; private set; }
    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public static void RunInUI(Action action, bool wait = false)
    {
        Task t = new Task(action);
        t.RunSynchronously(MainThread);
        if (wait) t.Wait();
    }

    public void ShowMainForm()
    {
        MainWindow = new MainWindow();
        MainWindow.Closed += main_Closed;
        MainWindow.Show();
    }

    void main_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.Shutdown();
        Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);
    }


    #endregion
}
```